# JAVA SynchronousQueue multithreading help watching a directory, can't force a timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I have a JavaFX application that listens to a directory for a file to appear.  I have created a separate thread and a SynchronousQueue to handle communication between the main thread and the thread I created for listening to the directory, so my application does not hang while in the loop that polls the WatchKey events.  here is a example of the WitchDir class that watches the directory...

```
public class WatchDir extends Thread {
    public static SynchronousQueue<String> syncQueue = new SynchronousQueue<String>();

@Override
public void run(){ 
    boolean continue = true;
    while(continue) {
        // wait for key to be signalled
        WatchKey key;
        try {
            key = watcher.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            return;
        }

        for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
            Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

            // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
            WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
            Path name = ev.context();
            Path child = dir.resolve(name);

            // TODO: handle OVERFLOW event??
            if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                continue;
            }else if(kind == ENTRY_CREATE){

                if(name.endsWith(type.getFileName())){
                    //do stuff...i.e. parse the file contents into csv

                    try{
                        syncQueue.put("csv string");                            
                    }catch(InterruptedException iex){                           
                        iex.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    }
              }

etc...
```

Then in another class, A method polls the SynchronousQueue in a loop.  This works great when I place a file in the watched directory, but it never times out if a file does not get placed in the directory.  I am guessing because it is resetting the poll every time in the loop.  I don't think I am doing it correctly, but I am having a hard time with Java API documentation and/or finding an example. I cannot seem to throw an InterruptedException. Here is basically what I am trying...

```
try{
     watchDir = new WatchDir(WATCHDIR, false, MercG_PWS);
     watchDir.start();
     String result = "";

     //I don't think the following loop is correct....
     while(result.isEmpty()){
         try{
             result = WatchDir.syncQueue.poll(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }catch(InterruptedException iex){
            Log.errorDialog(Log.MODERATE, "timed out.", false);
            watchDir.interrupt();
            break;
        }
    }

}catch(IOException iox){
    iox.printStackTrace();           
}
```

Comment: I dont see your code breaking from top while loop that is infinite since continue is always true and is not changing (at least not in the code you posted).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using this self-made and inefficient polling at all? Java has a built-in mechanism for observing directories.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html